# ウェブアプリケーションとしての導入について

Tags: google-apps-script

閲覧ありがとうございます。
GASでの開発中に次のような事象が発生しており困っています。

## ■発生している問題

[公開]タブ>[ウェブアプリケーションとしての導入…]をクリック後、
「データを取得しています…」という画面が表示された状態で止まってしまう。

## ■やったこと

- Chromeのキャッシュの削除
- 違うスプレッドシートで導入テスト

  - ⇒問題なく公開可能
- 対象のスクリプトが導入可能かどうか確認

  - ⇒別のスプレッドシートであれば導入可能

Googleのサーバ側の問題であるかもしれないのですが、同様の事象が発生しており解決した方がいらっしゃれば何か知見を伺えればと思い質問させて頂きました。
以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しましたので、同じところで躓いた人のために残しておきます。
どうやら「ウェブアプリケーションとしての導入…」は対象ドキュメントのオーナーでしかできない操作のようです。オーナー権限を譲渡してもらったら解決しました。
何かしらエラーメッセージ出してほしいですね。。

【備考：オーナーの譲渡方法】
　・ドライブでスクリプトの付属するドキュメントを右クリック
　・共有⇒詳細設定
　・オーナーの場合、人に付属する右側のプルダウンに「閲覧可」「編集可」に加えて「オーナー」が存在しますのでそちらを選択